# & in os.execute

Tags: lua

```
os.execute("start http://test.aspx?arg1=one&arg2=two")
```

I get this error:

> 'arg2' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows interprets `&` as command separator

```
os.execute'start "http://test.aspx?arg1=one&arg2=two"'
```

Answer (score 2):

In shell languages, `&` and `;` act as command separator. You need to enclose the command inside double-quotes for it to work..

```
os.execute("start \"http://test.aspx?arg1=one&arg2=two\"")
```

Or more simply:

```
os.execute([[start "http://test.aspx?arg1=one&arg2=two"]])
```

Comment: Also `os.execute('start "http://test.aspx?arg1=one&arg2=two"')` or `os.execute("start 'http://test.aspx?arg1=one&arg2=two'")`.

Comment: @lhf Yeah. But `[[` and `]]` provides for multi-line strings. Hence, I prefer them.

Comment: @lhf - Windows [doesn't](http://superuser.com/questions/324278/how-to-make-windows-command-prompt-treat-single-quote-as-though-it-is-a-double-q) consider single quotes as magic.